# Restore database by files from broken Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql

I'm pretty lost right now.

The RAID controller auf my server broke and all attached hard drives were corrupted. Luckily I copied the plain files off the server right before the crash (phew).

I set up the new server with Ubuntu 12.04 and a fresh mysql installation. I copied the backup off a server directly to the new one, without saving them to a windows machine (to prevent privileges errors).

My back up folder looks like this:

```
drwx------ 15 jensma jensma 4.0K Dec 12 18:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 76 jensma jensma 4.0K Nov 22 12:00 ..
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Nov 21 02:50 gamefilesenter
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Aug  5 00:17 circuitboard
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql  mysql     0 Oct 25 07:49 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql   26M Dec 12 02:22 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  5.0M Dec 12 18:09 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  5.0M Dec 12 02:22 ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Oct 25 07:49 mysql
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql     6 Oct 25 07:49 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Oct 25 07:49 performance_schema
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K May 25  2013 phpmyadmin
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K Jul  4 18:29 test
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4.0K May 19  2013 usr_web10_5
```

A folder contains data like this:

```
drwx------  2 mysql  mysql  4096 Aug  5 00:17 .
drwx------ 15 jensma jensma 4096 Dec 12 18:09 ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql    65 Jul 10 15:04 db.opt
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  8620 Aug  1 23:38 stat.frm
-rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  8700 Aug  5 00:17 user.frm
```

I just copied the whole content to /var/lib/mysql and ran

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld –innodb_log_file_size=5242880 –innodb_force_recovery=6
```

Well, the command kinda works - the shell shows up after half a minute. But the database is still empty :/

I'm pretty now to this. I do have full admin access to the server.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit 1:

```
ls -la /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql/*
```

gives:

```
ls: cannot access /var/lib/mysql/*: No such file or directory
/var/lib/mysql:
total 36928
drwx------ 15 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 14 19:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 root  root      4096 Dec 14 18:07 ..
drwx------  2 root  root      4096 Dec 14 19:06 gamefilesenter
drwx------  2 root  root      4096 Dec 14 19:06 circuitboard
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root         0 Dec 14 19:06 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 27262976 Dec 14 19:06 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  5242880 Dec 14 19:06 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  5242880 Dec 14 19:06 ib_logfile1
drwx------ 15 mysql root      4096 Dec 14 19:03 mysql
-rw-rw----  1 root  root         6 Dec 14 19:06 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 14 18:07 performance_schema
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 14 19:06 phpmyadmin
drwx------  2 mysql root      4096 Dec 14 19:06 test
drwx------  2 root  root      4096 Dec 14 19:06 usr_web10_5
```

Edit 2:

A little update:

The databases are created, but empty. The users are created and their priviliges are applied correctly to the databases. No content, tough :(

Comment: Show the output of `ls -la /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql/*` please, and the mysql logs.

Comment: Sure, just a sec. Editing the first post.

Comment: Updated info :)

Comment: Did you copied files with mysql server stopped?

Answer (score 1):

From what i see there is nor IDB (InnoDB database file) or my MYD (MyISAM database file), all  you have is the db structure, frm files.

I think this guide can help you get your files back https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57157